# The escape character before % is giving the ! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> $ error

Tags: errors, hyperref

I am trying to include link in my references. The link contains **%** character in it. In order for **%** to behave as normal character I am escaping it with **\** character. But I am getting an

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.614 ...ia.org/wiki/Shamir\%27s_Secret_Sharing''}
```

error.

Here is the line that is producing this error

```
\hyperref[shamir]{''http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir\%27s_Secret_Sharing''}
```

I am using `hyperref` package for adding links.

Comment: You don't need the quotes: `\hyperref[shamir]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir\%27s_Secret_Sharing}`. In fact, the `'`'s put you into mathematics mode, hence the error about a missing `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with % but with the underscore!
Use this

```
\hyperref[shamir]{''http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir\%27s\_Secret\_Sharing''}
```

Comment: I understand now. Should have concentrated more on error. Thank you very much

Comment: `\hyperref[<label>]{<text>}` is an intern link with text `<text>` to a `\label{<label>}`, *not* a URI link to `<text>`!

Answer (score 5):

The underscore characters require math mode, they are used for subscripts there. Thus you need `\_` here for a underscore character.

Alternatively `\url` or `\nolinkurl` can be used. The latter is `\url` minus the link property.

An example with some variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing}

\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing}{%
  \nolinkurl{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir\%27s_Secret_Sharing}}

\urlstyle{same}
\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing}{%
  \nolinkurl{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir\%27s_Secret_Sharing}}

\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir\%27s_Secret_Sharing}{shamir}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Escaping the comment char via `\%` is needed, if the URL macros are used inside the argument of another macro.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I replace \hyperref with \url and it solved my problem