# URL causes Missing $ inserted error

Tags: errors, urls

I'm trying to add this to my bibliography:

```
\bibitem{nasa}Alliance, N.P.A.R.C. Computational fluid dynamics (CFD)  verification and validation web site: http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/wind/valid/lamcyl/Study1_files/Study1.html
```

But it says:

> ```
> ! Missing $ inserted.
> ```

I have written other webpages without problem, for example:

```
\bibitem{lorenab} Lorena A. Barba group. CFD Python: 12 steps to Navier Stokes. http://goo.gl/yVI2zk
```

What is happening?

Comment: the problem is the underscore in the url.  it's being interpreted as an indicator for a subscript.  wrap the url with `\url{...}`; this will need a package such as `hyperref`.  (i'm sure this has been answered before, but i can't find a reference.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I couldn't find a good duplicate either. The closest I got was [The escape character before % is giving the ! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> $ error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240109/35864), where I'm not too fond of the accepted answer. There is also [Missing $ inserted issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71215/35864). So you might as well go ahead and answer, you might want to mention that the `url` package is enough if one doesn't want hyper links as provided by `hyperref`.

Answer (score 13):

the problem is the underscore in the url.  it's being interpreted as an
indicator for a subscript, which requires math.  wrap the url with `\url` thus:

```
\url{http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/wind/valid/lamcyl/Study1_files/Study1.html}
```

this will require a package.
if you don't with to have hyperlinks, the `url` package will suffice.

```
\usepackage{url}
```

if you *do* wish to have hyperlinks, then use the `hyperref` package
(which loads `url`).  since this url is quite long, you may wish to allow
it to be broken across lines; the `breaklinks` option will enable this:

```
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
```

see the package documentation regarding the places where breaks are permitted.

the `url` package also has a (more complicated) line-breaking mechanism
available.  again, see the package documentation for details.

as reminded by @egreg, `[breaklinks]` works only if the output is `dvi`,
to be converted by `dvips` and further converted to `pdf` by an additional tool.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a small add-on: the `hyperref` package loads `url` internally, so there is really no need to load both.

Comment: @moewe -- thanks for that reminder.  i've added it to the answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `breaklinks` is only effective in `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` mode; with `pdftex` it's useless (but does no harm either).

Comment: @egreg -- i keep forgetting that (routinely use the `dvips+distill` method, which is more reliable when sent to the rip we use to make plates for the press).  what, if anything, is a viable alternative?

Comment: @barbarabeeton With `pdflatex` links *are* broken across lines; whether `\url` breaks or not, is another matter.

Comment: @egreg -- are links broken with `xetex`?